# HTML Purifier messing up table

Tags: htmlpurifier

I'm using *HTML Purifier* with *Laravel* and it is messing up tables.

Instead of displaying this:

```
<table class="table-stripped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Test</th>
            <th>Max score</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

HTML Purifier mess up the table above and turn it into this

```
<table class="table-stripped">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Test</th>
            <th>Max score</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody></tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I also tested this using `PHP Artisan Tinker`. See the picture below
[image: HTML Purifier output using Tinker.]

My `app/config/purifier.php`

```
<?php

return [
    'encoding'      => 'UTF-8',
    'finalize'      => true,
    'cachePath'     => storage_path('app/purifier'),
    'cacheFileMode' => 0755,
    'settings'      => [
        'default' => [
            'HTML.Doctype'             => 'HTML 4.01 Transitional',
            'HTML.Allowed'             => 'h2[style|class],h3[style|class],h4[style|class],h5[style|class],h6[style|class],div[class|style],section,b,strong,i[style|class],em,a[href|title|class],ul[style|class],ol[style|class],li[style|class],p[style|class],br,span[style|class],img[width|height|alt|src|class],table[style|class],tbody[style|class],thead[style|class],tr[style|class],th[style|class],td[style|class],button,p,object[type|width|data|height|name|form|usemap|class],embed[src|type|width|height|class],iframe[src|height|width|class|name]',
            'CSS.AllowedProperties'    => 'text-decoration,padding,color,background-color,text-align,margin,height,width,max-height,max-width',
            'AutoFormat.AutoParagraph' => false,
            'AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty'   => true,
            'Attr.EnableID' => 'true',
        ],
        "youtube" => [
            "HTML.SafeIframe"      => 'true',
            "URI.SafeIframeRegexp" => "%^(http://|https://|//)(www.youtube.com/embed/|player.vimeo.com/video/)%",
        ],
        'custom_definition' => [
            'id'  => 'html5-definitions',
            'rev' => 1,
            'debug' => false,
            'elements' => [
                // http://developers.whatwg.org/sections.html
                ['section', 'Block', 'Flow', 'Common'],
                ['nav',     'Block', 'Flow', 'Common'],
                ['article', 'Block', 'Flow', 'Common'],
                ['aside',   'Block', 'Flow', 'Common'],
                ['header',  'Block', 'Flow', 'Common'],
                ['footer',  'Block', 'Flow', 'Common'],
                ['table',  'Block', 'Flow', 'Common'],

                // Content model actually excludes several tags, not modelled here
                ['address', 'Block', 'Flow', 'Common'],
                ['hgroup', 'Block', 'Required: h2 | h3 | h4 | h5 | h6', 'Common'],

                // http://developers.whatwg.org/grouping-content.html
                ['figure', 'Block', 'Optional: (figcaption, Flow) | (Flow, figcaption) | Flow', 'Common'],
                ['figcaption', 'Inline', 'Flow', 'Common'],

                // http://developers.whatwg.org/the-video-element.html#the-video-element
                ['video', 'Block', 'Optional: (source, Flow) | (Flow, source) | Flow', 'Common', [
                    'src' => 'URI',
                    'type' => 'Text',
                    'width' => 'Length',
                    'height' => 'Length',
                    'poster' => 'URI',
                    'preload' => 'Enum#auto,metadata,none',
                    'controls' => 'Bool',
                ]],
                ['source', 'Block', 'Flow', 'Common', [
                    'src' => 'URI',
                    'type' => 'Text',
                ]],
                ['object', 'Block', 'Optional: (source, Flow) | (Flow, source) | Flow', 'Common', [
                    'data' => 'URI',
                    'form' => 'Text',
                    'name' => 'Text',
                    'usemap' => 'Text',
                    'type' => 'Text',
                    'width' => 'Length',
                    'height' => 'Length',
                ]],
                ['iframe', 'Block', 'Optional: (source, Flow) | (Flow, source) | Flow', 'Common', [
                    'src' => 'URI',
                    'name' => 'Text',
                    'class' => 'Text',
                    'usemap' => 'Text',
                    'width' => 'Length',
                    'height' => 'Length',
                ]],
                ['embed', 'Block', 'Optional: (source, Flow) | (Flow, source) | Flow', 'Common', [
                    'src' => 'URI',
                    'type' => 'Text',
                    'width' => 'Length',
                    'height' => 'Length',
                ]],

                //
                ['button', 'Inline', 'Flow', 'Common', [
                    'type' => 'Text',
                    'aria-label' => 'Text'
                ]],

                // http://developers.whatwg.org/text-level-semantics.html
                ['s',    'Inline', 'Inline', 'Common'],
                ['var',  'Inline', 'Inline', 'Common'],
                ['sub',  'Inline', 'Inline', 'Common'],
                ['sup',  'Inline', 'Inline', 'Common'],
                ['mark', 'Inline', 'Inline', 'Common'],
                ['wbr',  'Inline', 'Empty', 'Core'],

                // http://developers.whatwg.org/edits.html
                ['ins', 'Block', 'Flow', 'Common', ['cite' => 'URI', 'datetime' => 'CDATA']],
                ['del', 'Block', 'Flow', 'Common', ['cite' => 'URI', 'datetime' => 'CDATA']],
            ],
            'attributes' => [
                ['iframe', 'allowfullscreen', 'Bool'],
                ['table', 'height', 'Text'],
                ['td', 'border', 'Text'],
                ['th', 'border', 'Text'],
                ['tr', 'width', 'Text'],
                ['tr', 'height', 'Text'],
                ['tr', 'border', 'Text'],
            ],
        ],
        'custom_attributes' => [
            ['a', 'target', 'Enum#_blank,_self,_target,_top'],
        ],
        'custom_elements' => [
            ['u', 'Inline', 'Inline', 'Common'],
        ],
    ],

];
```

**How to solve this problem?**

I cannot disable Purifier because some users are able to create blog posts in HTML, so I need to display the HTML and Purifier seems to be the best option to disallow scripts and malicious attacks in case some hacker get access to those users' accounts.

Comment: This is purely a hunch - it might be completely wrong: Since the default HTML definition of HTML Purifier doesn't do this (see demo on site), have you tried removing the "table" element from the custom definition? Does it still do it then?

Comment: @pinkgothic I've tried what you suggested and the error continues :/

Comment: What does it say when you turn on error collection (http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#Core.CollectErrors) and output the errors (raw HTML Purifier example e.g. in the source code of demo.php (https://repo.or.cz/htmlpurifier-web.git/blob/b4f116b5aebdc688e6e4b458d5a790add6282cd5:/demo.php))? Anything useful?

Comment: I'll try that out and let you know soon